# Request PHP data from page

Tags: javascript, php, vba, excel

I'm requesting information from a webpage using Excel VBA. I'm trying to find which of the following methods is more effective in terms of reliability/performance.

**Method 1: Use MSXML2.ServerXMLHTT and request the data from the server like:**

```
Set objHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
   URL = "http://www.example.com/page"
   objHTTP.Open "POST", URL, False
   objHTTP.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)"
   objHTTP.send ("")
```

**Method 2 Use IE to navigate to the page and fetch the elements I need by getting the innerHTML of specific div id's. Like:**

```
sURL = "http://www.example.com/page"
Set oBrowser = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application") 'New InternetExplorer
oBrowser.navigate sURL

With oBrowser
    Do While .Busy Or .ReadyState <> 4: Loop
End With

Set HTMLDoc = oBrowser.Document
With HTMLDoc
  divID = HTMLDoc.getElementById("myId").innerHTML
End With

oBrowser.Quit
```

The data I'm trying to obtain from this page is the complete name of the user, address, and registration date (given his username). For that, I have a PHP script.

Which of these two methods will be faster, what if the user doesn't have IE installed (will the first method work)?

Comment: As this question is tagged "javascript", is the required data present in the page being requested even if Javascript is turned off?

Comment: Good question! I didn't think about that option.

Comment: there is no clear answer to this question ... both methods have adavantages / disadvantages. I personally prefer a third method (but similar to the first one) with using WinHttpRequest object. The greates advantage of method 1 (and for my method with the WinHttpRequest object) is, that you have full control over the communication between server and client - and that it doesn't matter if the IE is installed or not ... and it's much faster.

Comment: @cboden thanks for your answer. I'm leaning torwards the 1st (or 3rd) method too due to the reasons you point. Do you know of any resources, like code examples, I can use to further explore this question?